# Redis Lua Differetiating empty array and object

Tags: json, lua, redis, cjson

I encountered this bug in cjson lua when I was using a script in redis 3.2 to set a particular value in a json object.

Currently, the lua in redis does not differentiate between an empty json array or an empty json object. Which causes serious problems when serialising json objects that have arrays within them.

```
eval "local json_str = '{\"items\":[],\"properties\":{}}' return cjson.encode(cjson.decode(json_str))" 0
```

Result:

```
"{\"items\":{},\"properties\":{}}"
```

I found this solution https://github.com/mpx/lua-cjson/issues/11 but I wasn't able to implement in a redis script.

This is an unsuccessful attempt :

```
eval 

"function cjson.mark_as_array(t) 
local mt = getmetatable(t) or {} 
mt.__is_cjson_array = true 
return setmetatable(t, mt) 
end 
function cjson.is_marked_as_array(t) 
local mt = getmetatable(t) 
return mt and mt.__is_cjson_array end 
local json_str = '{\"items\":[],\"properties\":{}}' 
return cjson.encode(cjson.decode(json_str))" 

0
```

Any help or pointer appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two plans.

1. Modify the lua-cjson source code and compile redis, click [here](https://github.com/xiyuan-fengyu/redis-lua-cjson-empty-table-fix) for details.
2. Fix by code:

```
local now = redis.call("time")
-- local timestamp = tonumber(now[1]) * 1000 + math.floor(now[2]/1000)
math.randomseed(now[2])
local emptyFlag = "empty_" .. now[1] .. "_" .. now[2] .. "_" .. math.random(10000)
local emptyArrays = {}
local function emptyArray()
    if cjson.as_array then
        -- cjson fixed:  https://github.com/xiyuan-fengyu/redis-lua-cjson-empty-table-fix
        local arr = {}
        setmetatable(arr, cjson.as_array)
        return arr
    else
        -- plan 2
        local arr = {}
        table.insert(emptyArrays, arr)
        return arr
    end
end

local function toJsonStr(obj)
    if #emptyArrays > 0 then
        -- plan 2
        for i, item in ipairs(emptyArrays) do
            if #item == 0 then
                -- empty array, insert a special mark
                table.insert(item, 1, emptyFlag)
            end
        end

        local jsonStr = cjson.encode(obj)
        -- replace empty array
        jsonStr = (string.gsub(jsonStr, '%["' .. emptyFlag ..  '"]', "[]"))

        for i, item in ipairs(emptyArrays) do
            if item[1] == emptyFlag then
                table.remove(item, 1)
            end
        end
        return jsonStr
    else
        return cjson.encode(obj)
    end
end


-- example
local arr = emptyArray()
local str = toJsonStr(arr)
print(str) -- "[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Redis and dealing with JSON data, specifically when you have nested arrays and objects and need to preserve empty arrays, you can employ a combination of techniques to achieve the desired result. Here's a solution that might help you:

Use cjson.encode() Method: When you have your data ready to be stored in Redis, use the cjson.encode() method to convert your Lua table (which represents your JSON data) into a JSON string. This method is efficient and handles most of the data types seamlessly.

Replace Empty Objects with Arrays: After encoding your data, you might end up with empty objects {} instead of empty arrays []. To handle this, you can perform a string replacement operation on the JSON string. This can be done by searching for instances of {} and replacing them with [].