# Lua script converts empty array to object

Tags: java, redis, lua

Lua script converts empty array as an object. How to avoid conversion.

**test.lua**

```
local json_str = '{\"items\":[],\"properties\":{}}'
return cjson.encode(cjson.decode(json_str))
```

**Output**

```
redis-cli --eval test.lua
```

> "{\"items\":{},\"properties\":{}}"

items are an array [] but the output is an object {}

Comment: This was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43272872/12918181

Comment: In the above question, I am not able to find relation between emptyArray() and toJsonStr() function . Can you help me to modify second approach Fix by code an above answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between JSON object definition and lua table, that lua table has no type array.

Empty JSON array [] or object {} is converted to lua table {}, but empty lua table {} can be converted to array [] or object {}.

To my knowledge, cjson for redis has no solution for this problem at the moment, possible solution is mentioned in [Redis Lua Differetiating empty array and object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272872/12918181). (I can't argue if it works)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this great post](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=34a03f76-c299-46a3-bedb-dbc70c3c3f5f) you can set the following option to cjson:

```
cjson.encode_empty_table_as_object(false)
```

So `cjson.encode({dogs = {}})` resolves to `{"dogs": []}`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
`setmetatable(table, cjson.array_mt)`